# vite + react + ts + tailwind app breaks with {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css, vite, tsx

I've just started learning typescript and ran into an issue with importing images with it (getting an error with importing .png file). Followed this guide https://dev.to/minompi/add-images-to-a-react-project-with-typescript-4gbm. But started getting a new error:

```
[plugin:vite:css] [postcss] {(intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value)} is not a function  
/Users/misha/dev/post_project/frontend/src/css/index.css
```

[the error I get in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/touOQ.png)

Tried googling that and then uninstalling (still gave me that error with postcss) and then installing tailwind, but it haven't really changed anything. Deleting the import line in code also doesn't produce any other error than that.

how do i fix this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.